# Nginx - Redirect http to https (with Ports, Reverse Proxy)

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

ive been stuck on this issue for quite a while - google cant help either

I have the following nginx route, but when i try to access it (https://viewer.grieferbot.site:10923 for example, but the port is different every time) my browser just says "Cannot establish secure connection to (url)". When trying the same, but using "http", it works.

Unfortionatly, it has to be https, since i have to embed it into an IFrame

```
server {
    server_name viewer.grieferbot.site;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1$request_uri;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/viewer.grieferbot.site/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/viewer.grieferbot.site/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

Comment: Where are you listening for the port `10923`? I think you need a listener with ssl on that port and declare your certificates there for it to work.

Comment: @Geilmaker the port is different every time

Comment: How does the port get set? How do you get the port number? When does it change?